# Why do we need to use the cleanup function instead of writing the cleanup code inside useEffect only?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As the title suggests, why do we need to use the cleanup function? I read that the cleanup function gets executed first and then the code inside the useEffect is executed. So why can't we simply add the cleanup logic in the **beginning** of the useEffect and then the normal useEffect logic that we wanted?

```
const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0)

  const handler = () => {
    console.log('Clicked')
    setClickCount(clickCount + 1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handler)
    document.addEventListener('click', handler)
    // return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  })
```

Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/still-sunset-os893k?file=/src/index.js

Why removing the eventListener everytime first and then adding a new one doesn't work? Why do we need to add the code to remove it inside the cleanup function?

Comment: a) because when you unmount this component it will not cleanup the handler from the document. b) because on the second run of the effect the handler (in you case) will be a new function (a different reference since the function is re-declared) and so when trying to remove it, it will not be found on the list of handlers attached on the document.

Comment: cleanup function does not execute first, it's executed when component is updated or unmounted.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I think that could go into the answer section, because that answers the OP's question

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Why is a new reference to handler being created on every render? Shouldn't there be only one `handler`?

Comment: @ParthKapadia when you do `const handler = () => {...}` you create a new function. So on its re-render you get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanup functions are run when the component is unmounted or after each re-render.

So, once the component is unmounted, you may want to remove the event listeners it added, 'cleaning up' what the component did.

Regarding event listeners, there might be a specific occasion that you may not want to do that, but as a rule of thumb, you will probably want to.

Another example is using timers. When the component gets unmounted, you wouldn't want to keep a setTimeout() running or a setInterval, you would like to clear them:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

useEffect(()=>{

 const timer = setInterval(()=>{
   setCounter(counter++)
 }, 1000)

  //When the component is unmounted, I need to clear it!
  //otherwise it is going to have a memory leakeage.
  return ()=> clearTimeout(timer)
}, [])
```

As you see, the return function "cleans up" whatever you did when the component gets unmounted.

As stated in the [docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup
> when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects
> run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans
> up effects from the previous render before running the effects next
> time

Comment: The cleanup methods do not run only on `unmount` the also run whenever the `useEffect` is re-run due to a change in its dependency array.

Comment: In the above-mentioned code sandbox...When I click, the component isn't unmounted, right? It is just re-rendering. So why doesn't adding a removeEventListener at the start of the useEffect achieve the same result? It should remove the previously added eventListener and then add a new one. So at all times there is only 1 event listener (but this is not happening). What am I missing?

Comment: It is removed, and the it is added again if the component gets re rendered.